# notifyItemInserted in runOnUiThread not work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For me, `notifyItemInserted` in `runOnUiThread` does not work.
I have `runOnUiThread` in `asyncTask` after download each file:

```
  ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
  imageModel.setName("تصویر " );
  imageModel.setUrl(aFile.getName());
  imageModel.ImageFile = localFile;
  data.add(imageModel);
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(data.size() - 1);
       }
  });
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not work'? Can you be more specific? Maybe post the error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to why it isn't working but I would recommend calling `publishProgress()` and then in `onProgressUpdate()` in your asynctask put your adapter call without the runOnUiThread.